# Appending in Python 3 from a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def add():
    aList = input("Enter file name with file extension too: ")
    file = open(aList, "a")
    txt = input("Enter the text you would like to add on to the txt file: ")
    aList.append (txt);
    print ("Updated List : ", aList)
```

I need this to append on to an external file like this:

```
NIGHT
SMOKE
GHOST
TOOTH
ABOUT
CAMEL
BROWN
FUNNY
CHAIR
PRICE
```

This list is called "List.txt"
I input this as the first variable and for the second variable I input "Hello" but I'm not really sure why it's giving me an error.
I just need it to add on to this list...

Comment: Hi @ruben-fontes, can you give us the error, please?

Comment: careful about indentation -> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a file in append-Mode, you can simply use write to add the text at the end of the file. The additional '\n' inserts a line break so the new input will be on an extra line.

```
aList = input("Enter the file name with the file extension too: ")
file = open(aList, "a")
txt = input("Enter the text you would like to add on to the txt file: ")
file.write(txt + '\n');
file.close()
print ("Updated List : ", aList)
```

Also please make sure that you close the file at the end of use. Or even better use the with statement which will close the file at the and of the block.

```
aList = input("Enter the file name with the file extension too: ")
with open(aList, "a") as file:
    txt = input("Enter the text you would like to add on to the txt file: ")
    file.write(txt + '\n')
print("Updated List : ", aList)
```

Comment: Ah okay, Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I did know about the file.close() part, i just forgot to add it in.

Comment: @RubenFontes I am glad that I could help you. I myself sometimes forget to close the file. Therefore I prefer the with statement :)